# Angular2 - using CryptoJS

Tags: angular

a coleague and are completly new to Angular 2. We created a new project using angular-cli and started implementing our stuff. We are now at a point where we are in need of a crypto library. We did some google research but unfortunally there seems to be no easy Howto for how to proceed here. So we put together what we've found in the net and of course - it is not working. No idea why....

So - what we did:

This is our project:
https://github.com/den1982/moneyjinn-client

1. We installed crypto-js with npm (see: https://github.com/den1982/moneyjinn-client/blob/master/package.json)
2. We added The typings to be able to use crypto-js in TypeScript (see: https://github.com/den1982/moneyjinn-client/blob/master/typings/cryptojs/cryptojs.d.ts)
3. We added the "reference path" line in our service where we want to use CryptoJS (seee: https://github.com/den1982/moneyjinn-client/blob/master/src/app/services/rest.service.ts)
4. We added the crypto-js files to our index.html (see: https://github.com/den1982/moneyjinn-client/blob/master/src/index.html)

At first - the lines in index.html don't work because the scripts are not there when "ng serve" is called - the path just don't match - node_modules is not accessable inside the "webroot".

The important thing it - it just does not compile. The error message is:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/services/rest.service.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:/Users/xxxx/git/moneyjinn-client/src/app/services/rest.service.ts (25,5): Cannot find name 'CryptoJS'.)
    at _checkDiagnostics (C:\Users\xxxx\git\moneyjinn-client\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:116:15)
    at C:\Users\xxxx\git\moneyjinn-client\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:141:17
 @ ./src/app/services/restuser.service.ts 18:0-45
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
```

We also tried what is described on http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html but it still does not compile.

1. we ran `npm install --save @types/cryptojs`
2. we added `import * as CryptoJS from "cryptojs"` to our service

The new error is:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/services/rest.service.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:/Users/xxxx/git/moneyjinn-client/src/app/services/rest.service.ts (6,27): File 'C:/Users/xxxx/git/moneyjinn-client/node_modules/@types/cryptojs/index.d.ts' is not a module.)
    at _checkDiagnostics (C:\Users\xxxx\git\moneyjinn-client\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:116:15)
    at C:\Users\xxxx\git\moneyjinn-client\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:141:17
 @ ./src/app/services/restuser.service.ts 18:0-45
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
```

What are we missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Olli, i think you have forgotten to mention the reference to cryptoJS in your tsConfig.json file. I am able to run your code after adding reference to index.d.ts, that means you have tell to the compiler about the libraries you load. Refer this link, [click here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/types-2.0/crypto-js/index.d.ts)

below is change required in tsconfig.json,

`"files": [
    "index.d.ts"
  ]`

Comment: The two last steps from my initial posting + your tsconfig.json modification did the trick. The steps 3+4 in the first part of my initial posting are not needed at all. Thanks!